# Difference in two calculated values in spotfire graphical table

Tags: spotfire

I have 2 calculated value in spotfire graphical table. Is there a way to add third calculated value which shows the difference of the two.

Answer (score 0):

yes. if your first calculated value is `Sum([Column 1])` and your second is `Avg([Column 2])` then in your third calculated value write `Sum([Column 1]) - Avg([Column 2])`